# mgcv gamm function, and varComb

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I have been trying to fit multiple variance functions within a `gamm` using varComb.

I am using the last R and `mgcv` versions, and I've tried this on several different models, with and without moderate collinearity (no severe collinearity issues).

I won't post a reproducible example here, because I get the same error no matter what data set I'm using, what model I'm fitting, what predictors I include, etc. I just want to know if others are having this problem, and whether anyone has gotten S. Wood et al. to respond to inquiries about it, and if yes, what they said.

The error is:

> NA/NaN function evaluationSingular precision matrix in level -8, block 1Error in environment(attr(ret$lme$modelStruct$varStruct, "formula")) <- .GlobalEnv :
>         attempt to set an attribute on NULL

I understand what the 'Singular precision matrix' bit is about, but the last "attempt to set an attribute on NULL" has got me confused. The `mgcv` change log (http://cran.seoul.go.kr/web/packages/mgcv/ChangeLog) says that `varComb` functionality was added to `mgcv` in 2018.

Comment: A reproducible example is still necessary so we can explore possible answers. You can provide a dput(), simulate data, or use an existing dataset like `iris`.

Comment: Here's an example using iris.